# Documenting different argument possibilities on same function

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring, sphinx-napoleon

I'm using Google-style docstrings with sphinx.ext.autodoc to automatically generate documentation for my functions, and make sure they are properly self-documented in the code.

I have a function `def myfunc(id=None, size=None, hash=None)` that returns information based on `id` **or** `size + hash`. If we have `id` as an argument, `size` and `hash` are not needed, if we have `size` and `hash` as arguments, then `id` isn't needed.

With sphinx, it is possible to specify an optional argument, but in this case we don't know what will be mandatory and what will be optional. Here's an example:

```
def get_file(id=0, size=0, hash="")
    """
    Get file metadata.

    Args:
        id (int): id of the file.
        size (int): file size in bytes.
        hash (str): md5 hash of file.

    Returns:
        file_data (str): metadata information about the file.
    """
    if id:
        # Get file with id.
        ...
    elif size and hash:
        # Get file with size and hash.
        ...
    else:
        # Bad arguments, handle error.
        ...

    return file_data
```

The question is: **how to tell what arguments are necessary in the docstring?**

You could easily argue that the function itself is the issue, that both argument pairs should be in separate functions even if the result is the same:

```
def get_file_by_id(id)
    """
    Get file metadata from id.

    Args:
        id (int): id of the file.

    Returns:
        file_data (str): metadata information about the file.
    """

    # Get file with id.
    ...

    return file_data

def get_file_by_hash(size, hash)
    """
    Get file metadata from hash.

    Args:
        size (int): file size in bytes.
        hash (str): md5 hash of file.

    Returns:
        file_data (str): metadata information about the file.
    """

    # Get file with hash+size.
    ...

    return file_data
```

But in this case a single function would be preferred if possible, since the function is a binding to another API that uses a single function.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, [here](http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_google.html), the following example method definition:

```
def module_level_function(param1, param2=None, *args, **kwargs):
```

Has the docstring defined as:

```
Args:
    param1 (int): The first parameter.
    param2 (:obj:`str`, optional): The second parameter. Defaults to None.
        Second line of description should be indented.
    *args: Variable length argument list.
    **kwargs: Arbitrary keyword arguments.
```

So, you explicitly state what is *optional* as indicated, otherwise it would be understood as a mandatory argument.

Comment: This tells if the argument is optional, but if my case would apply to this example, **param1** would become optional if **param2** is used.

Comment: That's a bit hard to follow for its usage. If you are designing a function that takes optional parameters, then it is understood that it is exactly *that*. If the pair of those arguments need to be given together, you might want to put them together in a named tuple or some other helpful structure. That would probably be the better design option.

Comment: Personally, I think you should stick to splitting your functions for the sake of clarity and explicitness. Also, makes the documentation easier to write.

Comment: A tuple `(size, hash)` would simplify the issue, but we are still left with a function that takes `id` **or** `(size, hash)`. I agree that the usage is complicated, I'm open to any alternatives.

Comment: I'm not sure how this binding to the API is set up. But, what you can do is have a single method that your API communicates to, and in that method you look at the payload you receive. From that payload, you see what parameters are provided. Based on what is provided, you call the appropriate method. Otherwise you raise for not meeting the contract requirements.